# SQLite CASE/WHEN isnumeric query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following code that works in SQL:

```
"(CASE WHEN isnumeric(Installation) > 0 THEN cast(Installation as bigint) ELSE null END) "
```

I am trying to convert it to work in SQLite, but having trouble since I have very little experience in SQLite. Basically I want to cast/convert my stringcolumn (Installation) to a bigint,  but need the validation to make sure it only contains numeric characters.

I have tried the following 3 variations, but not having luck. Just getting errors saying could not execute query

```
("(CASE WHEN Installation GLOB '*[^0-9]*' THEN cast(Installation as bigint) ELSE null END)");

("(SELECT Installation from ShortCycleWorkOrderCompletions WHERE Installation = REGEXP '*[^0-9]*'");

("(CASE WHEN REGEXP(Installation, '*[^0-9]*') THEN cast(Installation as bigint) ELSE null END");
```

Don't need all 3 to work, just one, and these were what I have tried.

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not load an entity: [MapCall.Common.Model.Entities.ShortCycleWorkOrderCompletion#666][SQL: SELECT shortcycle0_.Id as Id510_0_, shortcycle0_.SAPCommunicationError as SAPCommu2_510_0_, shortcycle0_.SAPErrorCode as SAPError3_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ActiveMQStatus as ActiveMQ4_510_0_, shortcycle0_.WorkOrderNumber as WorkOrde5_510_0_, shortcycle0_.MiscInvoice as MiscInvo6_510_0_, shortcycle0_.BackOfficeReview as BackOffi7_510_0_, shortcycle0_.CompletionStatus as Completi8_510_0_, shortcycle0_.Notes as Notes510_0_, shortcycle0_.AdditionalWorkNeeded as Additio10_510_0_, shortcycle0_.Purpose as Purpose510_0_, shortcycle0_.TechnicalInspectedOn as Technic12_510_0_, shortcycle0_.TechnicalInspectedBy as Technic13_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ServiceFound as Service14_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ServiceLeft as Service15_510_0_, shortcycle0_.OperatedPointOfControl as Operate16_510_0_, shortcycle0_.AdditionalInformation as Additio17_510_0_, shortcycle0_.CurbBoxMeasurementDescription as CurbBox18_510_0_, shortcycle0_.Safety as Safety510_0_, shortcycle0_.HeatType as HeatType510_0_, shortcycle0_.MeterPositionLocation as MeterPo21_510_0_, shortcycle0_.MeterDirectionalLocation as MeterDi22_510_0_, shortcycle0_.MeterSupplementalLocation as MeterSu23_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ReadingDevicePositionalLocation as Reading24_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ReadingDeviceSupplementalLocation as Reading25_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ReadingDeviceDirectionalLocation as Reading26_510_0_, shortcycle0_.FSRId as FSRId510_0_, shortcycle0_.SerialNumber as SerialN28_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ManufacturerSerialNumber as Manufac29_510_0_, shortcycle0_.MeterSerialNumber as MeterSe30_510_0_, shortcycle0_.DeviceCategory as DeviceC31_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ActionFlag as ActionFlag510_0_, shortcycle0_.Installation as Install33_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ActivityReason as Activit34_510_0_, shortcycle0_.OldMeterSerialNumber as OldMete35_510_0_, shortcycle0_.QualityIssue as Quality36_510_0_, shortcycle0_.ReceivedAt as ReceivedAt510_0_, shortcycle0_.ShortCycleWorkOrderId as ShortCy38_510_0_, cast(shortcycle0_.WorkOrderNumber as varchar(12)) as formula90_0_, (CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('SUCCESS', UPPER(cast(shortcycle0_.SAPErrorCode as varchar(8000)))) > 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  as formula91_0_, (CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('SUCCESS', UPPER(cast(shortcycle0_.ActiveMQStatus as varchar(8000)))) > 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as formula92_0_, (CASE WHEN (NOT TRIM(shortcycle0_.Installation) GLOB '*[^0-9]*') AND TRIM(shortcycle0_.Installation) like '_%' THEN CAST(TRIM(shortcycle0_.Installation) AS shortcycle0_.BIGINT) ELSE null END) as formula93_0_ FROM ShortCycleWorkOrderCompletions shortcycle0_ WHERE shortcycle0_.Id=?] ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
near ".": syntax error
    at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, String optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister persister)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, String optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister persister)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader.Load(ISessionImplementor session, Object id, Object optionalObject, Object optionalId)
   at NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader.Load(Object id, Object optionalObject, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.LoadFromDatasource(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.Load(LoadEvent event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType options)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType loadType)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(String entityName, Object id)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(Type entityClass, Object id)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get[T](Object id)
   at MMSINC.Data.NHibernate.SessionWrapper.Get[T](Object id) in C:\Solutions\mmsinc\MMSINC.Core\Data\NHibernate\SessionWrapper.cs:line 511
   at MMSINC.Data.NHibernate.RepositoryBase`1.Find(Int32 id) in C:\Solutions\mmsinc\MMSINC.Core\Data\NHibernate\RepositoryBase.cs:line 104
   at MMSINC.Utilities.ActionHelper`4.DoEditWithArgs[TModel](Int32 id, ActionHelperDoEditArgs args, Action`1 onModelFound) in C:\Solutions\mmsinc\MMSINC.Core.Mvc\Utilities\ActionHelper.cs:line 560
   at MapCallMVC.Areas.ShortCycle.Controllers.ShortCycleWorkOrderCompletionController.Edit(Int32 id) in C:\Solutions\mapcall_mvc\MapCallMVC\Areas\ShortCycle\Controllers\ShortCycleWorkOrderCompletionController.cs:line 107
   at MapCallMVC.Tests.Controllers.ShortCycleWorkOrderCompletionControllerTest.TestEdit404sIfShortCycleWorkOrderCompletionNotFound() in C:\Solutions\mapcall_mvc\MapCallMVC.Tests\Areas\ShortCycle\Controllers\ShortCycleWorkOrderCompletionControllerTest.cs:line 165
```

Comment: **NOT** `Installation GLOB '*[^0-9]*' THEN CAST ....`

Comment: sqlite doesn't have a "bigint" type, btw. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html is a must-read.

Comment: @alex **edit** your question to put the **complete** error

Comment: @DanielE. Added the complete error from the failing test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost the same answer :

```
CASE 
  WHEN
    (NOT TRIM(Installation) GLOB '*[^0-9]*') AND TRIM(Installation) like '_%'
  THEN CAST(TRIM(Installation) AS BIGINT)
END AS intInstallation
```

Explanation :

- `[^0-9]` = every character that's not a number
- With the `NOT` you get all the installation who doesn't have a character that's not a number
- '_%' wildcard :  `_` any character once and `%` 0 or more of any character.

Since your edit, I look at the query :

```
THEN CAST(TRIM(shortcycle0_.Installation) AS shortcycle0_.BIGINT)
```

Replace it with :

```
THEN CAST(TRIM(shortcycle0_.Installation) AS BIGINT)
```

Comment: Yeah copy/paste *is very particular*!

Comment: the query is still not working and I have 0 idea why

Comment: @alex you didn't give us the **exact** error... Can you edit your question ?

Comment: NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query.....System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
near ".": syntax error

Comment: @DanielE. who's crying? If you did not comment you would be downvoted by now. But didn't you bother to write your own code from scratch? Plain copy/paste?

Comment: my query only has `as BIGINT`, and I only say `Installation` but I tried changing it to `shortcycle0_.Installation` and had no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use the below condition, which checks the existence of non numerical characters and the length of the trimmed value of `Installation`:

```
CASE 
  WHEN
    (NOT TRIM(Installation) GLOB '*[^0-9]*') AND (LENGTH(TRIM(Installation)) > 0)
  THEN CAST(TRIM(Installation) AS BIGINT)
END
```

Note that the data type `BIGINT` in SQLite, is actually `INTEGER` (1-8 bytes signed integer).